# Как сделать заполнение таблицы случайными числами без повторений?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

Задача: по кнопке создается таблица 5 x 5 и заполняется в случайном порядке числами от 1 до 25. Вопрос: как сделать, чтобы в ячейках числа были без повтора?

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

$('#createTable').click(function () {
    $('#shulteTable table').remove();
    var table = $('<table id="game_table">');
    for (r = 0; r < 5; ++r) {
        var rows = $('<tr>');
        for (c = 0; c < 5; ++c) {
            var tds = $('<td>');
            rows.append(tds).append();
            var rand = getRandomInt(1, 25);
                tds.append(rand);
    }
    table.append(rows);
}
$('#shulteTable').append(table);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Создать массив из чисел от одного до двадцати пяти и перемешать.

Код внутри функции параметра `setInterval`.

```js
var timer = null;
function startTimer() {
  if (timer)
    return;
    
  timer = setInterval(function() {
    var a = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 25; i++)
      a.push(i);
    a.sort(function() { return Math.random() - 0.5; });
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(a));

    var table = $('table');
    table.empty();

    var index = 0;
    for (r = 0; r < 5; ++r) {
      var row = $('<tr>');
      for (c = 0; c < 5; ++c) {
        row.append('<td>' + a[index++] + '</td>');
      }
      table.append(row);
    }
  }, 200);
}
function stopTimer() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = null;
}
startTimer();
```

```css
td {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1></table>
<br/>
<button onclick="stopTimer()">Stop</button>
<button onclick="startTimer()">Start</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помог!

Comment: В explorer Не работает данный код. Указывает на синтаксическую ошибку в строке a.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);

Comment: @Павел хорошо, обойдемся без стрелочной функции

Comment: Да. спасибо. Только в процессе изучения JS. Буду признателен за подсказки в изучении материалов по JS - книги, курсы

Comment: @Павел Здесь где-то был вопрос на эту тему.