# Как вывести числа в случайном порядке?

Tags: javascript

Вывести таблицу 10 × 10, заполненную числами от 1 до 100 (таблица создаётся динамически)
Вывел числа от 1 до 100. Как их перемешать теперь?

```js
let colTable = document.getElementsByClassName('col');

for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    colTable[i].innerHTML += i+1;
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать заполнение таблицы случайными числами без повторений?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/839644/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9)

Answer (score 4):

Перемешайте с помощью [алгоритма Фишера-Йетса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0).

Вероятно, будет проще сделать это в массиве, потом уже загрузить в таблицу.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, не настолько элегантно, как алгоритмический подход, но с задачей справляется

```js
let arr = [];

// Создаем массив чисел от 1 до 10
for(let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    arr.push(i);
}

// arr.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());
   
// Не стрелочная функция
arr.sort(function(){ return 0.5 - Math.random()});

console.log('Массив с случайным порядком элементов: ', arr);
```

Comment: `arr.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());`

Comment: @Igor, исправил

Comment: Как написать не используя стрелочную функцию? Я не проходил еще

Comment: @IhorStoner, Добавил вариант с использованием классической анонимной функции. Стрелочную закомментировал